# returning 2D Object type array in Java

Tags: java, serialization

This is my code snippet.I want to return 2D Object type array from the file data.txt
But i am getting error in the line labeled (1).
How can i achieve this.

```
Object data[][]=new Object[200][3];
try {
    ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.txt"));
    data=ois.readObject();  // error line!!!(1)
} catch(Exception exc) {
    System.out.println("error reading data.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`readObject()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29) returns an `Object`. If you know that the object is infact a `Object[][]`, then you can cast it:

```
data = (Object[][]) ois.readObject();
```

Also: you don't need create the 2D array in the first line, as that object will be discarded when you replace it with the one read from the file.